# How to show phone contacts in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, contacts

Following is my code, actually on screen it's not showing me any contact. In emulator I have 5 contacts added. Please tell me what to do.

```
{
    //some code
    Cursor cur = getContacts();
    String[] fields = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                                R.layout.list_view_item_new,
                                cur,
                                fields,
                                new int[] {R.id.contactEntryText});
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private Cursor getContacts() {  
    // Run query     
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = 
        new String[]{ ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                      ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME }; 
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;  
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + 
        " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";  
    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);  
}
```

Comment: Could you show us what list_view_item_new looks like?

Comment: thanks for pointing in that direction actually i was using linear layout inside that i have textview. now i have deleted linear layout . i am getting my list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have copied and executed almost the same code and it works:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Cursor cur = getContacts();

        ListView lv = getListView();

       String[] fields = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};

       SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = 
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                                        R.layout.main,
                                        cur,
                                        fields,
                                        new int[] {R.id.txtbox});
          lv.setAdapter(adapter);         
    }    

    private Cursor getContacts() {  
        // Run query     
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = 
                new String[]{ ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                              ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME }; 
            String selection = null;
            String[] selectionArgs = null;  
            String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + 
                " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";  
            return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }
```

Please check if you have done anything wrong in the textview implementation?

Comment: For those who want also to have a projection on the phone number. I tried this example but it was giving me an error saying invalid column data1. Here's the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811780/android-contact-phone-number-using-loader-invalid-column-data1

Answer (score 1):

First I would just narrow the problem.

1) Check if you have permissions for reading contacts

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

2) Check if cursor have any results

```
cur.getCount()
```

Comment: androidmanifest file have this permission and getcount() returns 5 but still i am not getting values in adapter. Is there any way to check row data in cursor?? if in debuging we can check, then please tell me which property to check?? thanks in advance..

Comment: @neha you can always iterate through cursor like : 'while (c.moveToNext())...' but one things that bother me. Once you use 'ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME' and once 'ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME'. Are those same?