# android get all contacts

Tags: android

How can I get all the names of the contacts in my Android and put them into array of strings?

Comment: have You tried to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html ?

Comment: [check this](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/3/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get phone contacts in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133163/how-to-get-phone-contacts-in-android)

Comment: Added a small library on [Github Repository](https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/android-contact-extractor) to fetch contacts

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Try this too,

```
private void getContactList() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);

    if ((cur != null ? cur.getCount() : 0) > 0) {
        while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Log.i(TAG, "Name: " + name);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Phone Number: " + phoneNo);
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
    if(cur!=null){
        cur.close();
    }
}
```

If you need more reference means refer this link [Read ContactList](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2011/05/contacts-api-20-and-above-android.html)

Comment: thanks for help, how can i show all the name in an ListView?(that i will can see all the contacts name in my phone in another windows)? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165599/how-to-show-phone-contacts-in-a-listview This is the thing you are looking for.. I know you would accept it as answer if I put copy paste code here...

Comment: Why does everyone include the `if (cur.getCount() > 0) {`? Cursor is supposed to start *before* the first item.

Comment: Hello, I tried something similar, but it didn't work. Here is my question, I would really appreciate your help! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097844/get-contact-name/35098111#35098111

Comment: For some reason this code gets each contact twice. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @Aerrow  some times get some contacts twice.Do you solve this   issues?

Comment: do not forget to close the cursor!

Comment: DO NOT use this code. It queries for all contacts, and then executes additional query for each single contact. Terrible performance - might take more than 10 seconds to run on a real device.

Comment: I am getting always Zero(0) in `hasPhoneNumber` variable    `int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));` because of that I cant get Phone Number.. please help me..

Comment: Hey @MikeL,
What if any new contact is added into the device, how to refresh the list i will get above to the new contact. Should i refresh the whole list every time on app launch ?

Comment: Can I get blocked contacts, blocked by the user?

Comment: @MateenChaudhry yes you can, please user like  Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(BlockedNumbers.CONTENT_URI,
      new String[]{BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_ID, BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_ORIGINAL_NUMBER,
      BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_E164_NUMBER}, null, null, null);  for more https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/block-numbers

Comment: @AndrewNo you have to include the MIMETYPE you want in the selection argument. ContactContracts.Data.Minetype = ContactContracts.CommonDataTypes.Phone.ContentItemType

Comment: @Vasiliy is right, if your contacts are less you maybe deceived it is fast, but problematic for actual users who have large contacts.

Answer (score 21):

Get all contacts in less than a second and without any load in your activity.
Follow my steps works like a charm.

```
ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
};

private void getContactList() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    if (cursor != null) {
        HashSet<String> mobileNoSet = new HashSet<String>();
        try {
            final int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
            final int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

            String name, number;
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
                number = cursor.getString(numberIndex);
                number = number.replace(" ", "");
                if (!mobileNoSet.contains(number)) {
                    contactList.add(new Contact(name, number));
                    mobileNoSet.add(number);
                    Log.d("hvy", "onCreaterrView  Phone Number: name = " + name
                            + " No = " + number);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Contacts

```
public class Contact {
public String name;
public String phoneNumber;

public Contact() {
}

public Contact(String name, String phoneNumber ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

}
```

Benefits

- less than a second
- without load
- ascending order
- without duplicate contacts

Comment: this should be accepted answer. because its so fast.  thanks

Comment: This is extremely better. A key point to mention is that the big difference here is that the used uri for this optimized solution is `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` which gives you an access to the `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` column directly.  
In the worse answer, you query the uri `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` which doesn't give you an access to the `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` column so you'll have to run another query using the id for each contact to access it.

Comment: it is wonderful

Comment: now this is perfect

Comment: ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI contains SPAM numbers and syncronized google business numbers. Suppose that you have 100 numbers in your contacts list, you'll get 250 records by using ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI. The reason is your numbers (100)  + google business numbers(50) + spam numbers (100) = 250. So that you must use ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, this will give you 100 record in our example. Iterate on each record and make another cursor query for each record to get contact number from ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI.

Comment: For sorting use " COLLATE NOCASE ASC" for case insensitive

Answer (score 18):

Get contacts info , photo contacts , photo uri and convert to Class model

1). Sample for Class model  :

```
    public class ContactModel {
        public String id;
        public String name;
        public String mobileNumber;
        public Bitmap photo;
        public Uri photoURI;
    }
```

2). get Contacts and convert to Model

```
     public List<ContactModel> getContacts(Context ctx) {
        List<ContactModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                    Cursor cursorInfo = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                    InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(ctx.getContentResolver(),
                            ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(id)));

                    Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(id));
                    Uri pURI = Uri.withAppendedPath(person, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

                    Bitmap photo = null;
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    }
                    while (cursorInfo.moveToNext()) {
                        ContactModel info = new ContactModel();
                        info.id = id;
                        info.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        info.mobileNumber = cursorInfo.getString(cursorInfo.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        info.photo = photo;
                        info.photoURI= pURI;
                        list.add(info);
                    }

                    cursorInfo.close();
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Awesome function, just need to add one more line to close the cursor after finished the first while clause. Thanks a lot

Comment: storing all the bitmap can be a bad idea, for example you load 1000 of bitmap and user see only first 10.

Answer (score 17):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity 
                        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int CONTACTS_LOADER_ID = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(CONTACTS_LOADER_ID,
                                      null,
                                      this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.

        if (id == CONTACTS_LOADER_ID) {
            return contactsLoader();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        //The framework will take care of closing the
        // old cursor once we return.
        List<String> contacts = contactsFromCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
        // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
        // longer using it.
    }

    private  Loader<Cursor> contactsLoader() {
        Uri contactsUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI; // The content URI of the phone contacts

        String[] projection = {                                  // The columns to return for each row
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        } ;

        String selection = null;                                 //Selection criteria
        String[] selectionArgs = {};                             //Selection criteria
        String sortOrder = null;                                 //The sort order for the returned rows

        return new CursorLoader(
                getApplicationContext(),
                contactsUri,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                sortOrder);
    }

    private List<String> contactsFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            do {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                contacts.add(name);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return contacts;
    }

}
```

and do not forget

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: Nice use of CursorLoader.  Do you know how to pull phone numbers from each of those contacts within a CursorLoader?

Comment: You can implement LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Contact> instead LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>. Where 'Contact' is your custom  entity.

Comment: @Artyom Can you please explain how to get the phonenumber part a bit?

Answer (score 6):

Improving on the answer of @Adiii - It Will Cleanup The Phone Number and Remove All Duplicates

Declare a Global Variable

```
// Hash Maps
Map<String, String> namePhoneMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Then Use The Function Below

```
private void getPhoneNumbers() {

        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        // Loop Through All The Numbers
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {

            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            // Cleanup the phone number
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll("[()\\s-]+", "");

            // Enter Into Hash Map
            namePhoneMap.put(phoneNumber, name);

        }

        // Get The Contents of Hash Map in Log
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : namePhoneMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Log.d(TAG, "Phone :" + key);
            String value = entry.getValue();
            Log.d(TAG, "Name :" + value);
        }

        phones.close();

    }
```

Remember in the above example the key is phone number and value is a name so read your contents like 998xxxxx282->Mahatma Gandhi instead of Mahatma Gandhi->998xxxxx282

Answer (score 3):

```
Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
String aNameFromContacts[] = new String[contacts.getCount()];  
String aNumberFromContacts[] = new String[contacts.getCount()];  
int i = 0;

int nameFieldColumnIndex = contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
int numberFieldColumnIndex = contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

while(contacts.moveToNext()) {

    String contactName = contacts.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
    aNameFromContacts[i] =    contactName ; 

    String number = contacts.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);
    aNumberFromContacts[i] =    number ;
i++;
}

contacts.close();
```

The result will be aNameFromContacts array full of contacts. Also ensure that you have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

in main.xml

Comment: thanks alot i will try it,if i have further questions i will ask you

Comment: thanks for help, how can i show all the name in an ListView?(that i will can see all the contacts name in my phone in another windows)? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165599/how-to-show-phone-contacts-in-a-listview This is the thing you are looking for.. I know you would accept it as answer if I put copy paste code here...

Comment: This answer is wrong. `PhoneLookup.NUMBER` is not a column in `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`, `numberFieldColumnIndex` always returning `-1`.

Comment: It should be like this: 
`Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null); while (phones.moveToNext()) { String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Pho‌​ne.DISPLAY_NAME)); String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NU‌​MBER)); } phones.close();`

Comment: Hello, I tried something similar, but it didn't work. Here is my question, I would really appreciate your help! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097844/get-contact-name/35098111#35098111

Comment: @gunner_dev please write a new answer if you're sure this answer *including your edit* will work.

Answer (score 2):

**This is the Method to get contact list Name and Number**

```
 private void getAllContacts() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id},
                        null);
                if (phoneCursor != null) {
                    if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

   //At here You can add phoneNUmber and Name to you listView ,ModelClass,Recyclerview
                        phoneCursor.close();
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//GET CONTACTLIST WITH ALL FIELD...       

public ArrayList < ContactItem > getReadContacts() {
         ArrayList < ContactItem > contactList = new ArrayList < > ();
         ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
         Cursor mainCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
         if (mainCursor != null) {
          while (mainCursor.moveToNext()) {
           ContactItem contactItem = new ContactItem();
           String id = mainCursor.getString(mainCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
           String displayName = mainCursor.getString(mainCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

           Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(id));
           Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);

           //ADD NAME AND CONTACT PHOTO DATA...
           contactItem.setDisplayName(displayName);
           contactItem.setPhotoUrl(displayPhotoUri.toString());

           if (Integer.parseInt(mainCursor.getString(mainCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            //ADD PHONE DATA...
            ArrayList < PhoneContact > arrayListPhone = new ArrayList < > ();
            Cursor phoneCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] {
             id
            }, null);
            if (phoneCursor != null) {
             while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
              PhoneContact phoneContact = new PhoneContact();
              String phone = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
              phoneContact.setPhone(phone);
              arrayListPhone.add(phoneContact);
             }
            }
            if (phoneCursor != null) {
             phoneCursor.close();
            }
            contactItem.setArrayListPhone(arrayListPhone);


            //ADD E-MAIL DATA...
            ArrayList < EmailContact > arrayListEmail = new ArrayList < > ();
            Cursor emailCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] {
             id
            }, null);
            if (emailCursor != null) {
             while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
              EmailContact emailContact = new EmailContact();
              String email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
              emailContact.setEmail(email);
              arrayListEmail.add(emailContact);
             }
            }
            if (emailCursor != null) {
             emailCursor.close();
            }
            contactItem.setArrayListEmail(arrayListEmail);

            //ADD ADDRESS DATA...
            ArrayList < PostalAddress > arrayListAddress = new ArrayList < > ();
            Cursor addrCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] {
             id
            }, null);
            if (addrCursor != null) {
             while (addrCursor.moveToNext()) {
              PostalAddress postalAddress = new PostalAddress();
              String city = addrCursor.getString(addrCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
              String state = addrCursor.getString(addrCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
              String country = addrCursor.getString(addrCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
              postalAddress.setCity(city);
              postalAddress.setState(state);
              postalAddress.setCountry(country);
              arrayListAddress.add(postalAddress);
             }
            }
            if (addrCursor != null) {
             addrCursor.close();
            }
            contactItem.setArrayListAddress(arrayListAddress);
           }
           contactList.add(contactItem);
          }
         }
         if (mainCursor != null) {
          mainCursor.close();
         }
         return contactList;
        }



    //MODEL...
        public class ContactItem {

            private String displayName;
            private String photoUrl;
            private ArrayList<PhoneContact> arrayListPhone = new ArrayList<>();
            private ArrayList<EmailContact> arrayListEmail = new ArrayList<>();
            private ArrayList<PostalAddress> arrayListAddress = new ArrayList<>();


            public String getDisplayName() {
                return displayName;
            }

            public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
                this.displayName = displayName;
            }

            public String getPhotoUrl() {
                return photoUrl;
            }

            public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
                this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
            }

            public ArrayList<PhoneContact> getArrayListPhone() {
                return arrayListPhone;
            }

            public void setArrayListPhone(ArrayList<PhoneContact> arrayListPhone) {
                this.arrayListPhone = arrayListPhone;
            }

            public ArrayList<EmailContact> getArrayListEmail() {
                return arrayListEmail;
            }

            public void setArrayListEmail(ArrayList<EmailContact> arrayListEmail) {
                this.arrayListEmail = arrayListEmail;
            }

            public ArrayList<PostalAddress> getArrayListAddress() {
                return arrayListAddress;
            }

            public void setArrayListAddress(ArrayList<PostalAddress> arrayListAddress) {
                this.arrayListAddress = arrayListAddress;
            }
        }

        public class EmailContact
        {
            private String email = "";

            public String getEmail() {
                return email;
            }

            public void setEmail(String email) {
                this.email = email;
            }
        }

        public class PhoneContact
        {
            private String phone="";

            public String getPhone()
            {
                return phone;
            }

            public void setPhone(String phone) {
                this.phone = phone;
            }
        }


        public class PostalAddress
        {
            private String city="";
            private String state="";
            private String country="";

            public String getCity() {
                return city;
            }

            public void setCity(String city) {
                this.city = city;
            }

            public String getState() {
                return state;
            }

            public void setState(String state) {
                this.state = state;
            }

            public String getCountry() {
                return country;
            }

            public void setCountry(String country) {
                this.country = country;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//In Kotlin     
private fun showContacts() {
        // Check the SDK version and whether the permission is already granted or not.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            requestPermissions(
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS),
                1001
            )
            //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method
        } else {
            // Android version is lesser than 6.0 or the permission is already granted.
            getContactList()
        }
    }
    private fun getContactList() {
        val cr: ContentResolver = requireActivity().contentResolver
        val cur: Cursor? = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null
        )
        if ((if (cur != null) cur.getCount() else 0) > 0) {
            while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
                val id: String = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)
                )
                val name: String = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                    )
                )
                if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                    val pCur: Cursor? = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        arrayOf(id),
                        null
                    )
                    pCur?.let {
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                            val phoneNo: String = pCur.getString(
                                pCur.getColumnIndex(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                                )
                            )
                            Timber.i("Name: $name")
                            Timber.i("Phone Number: $phoneNo")
                        }
                        pCur.close()
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        if (cur != null) {
            cur.close()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this method, and it is working perfectly.
It gets fav, picture, name, number etc. (All the details of the contact). And also it is not repetitive.

> List

```
private static List<FavContact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
```

> Method to get contacts

```
@SuppressLint("Range")
public static void readContacts(Context context) {

    if (context == null)
        return;

    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

    if (contentResolver == null)
        return;

    String[] fieldListProjection = {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI
            ,ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED
    };
    String sort = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " ASC";
    Cursor phones = contentResolver
            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
                    , fieldListProjection, null, null, sort);
    HashSet<String> normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound = new HashSet<>();

    if (phones != null && phones.getCount() > 0) {
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String normalizedNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (Integer.parseInt(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                if (normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound.add(normalizedNumber)) {

                    int id = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                    String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    int fav = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.STARRED));
                    boolean isFav;
                    isFav= fav == 1;

                    String uri = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
                    if(uri!=null){
                        contactList.add(new FavContact(id,isFav,uri,name,phoneNumber));
                    }
                    else{
                        contactList.add(new FavContact(id,isFav,name,phoneNumber));
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        phones.close();
    }
}
```

> Model Class

```
public class FavContact{

    private int id;

    private boolean isFavorite;

    private String image;

    private String name;

    private String number;
   

    public FavContact(int id,boolean isFavorite, String image, String name, String number){
        this.id=id;
        this.isFavorite = isFavorite;
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public FavContact(int id,boolean isFavorite, String name, String number){
        this.id=id;
        this.isFavorite = isFavorite;
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isFavorite() {
        return isFavorite;
    }

    public void setFavorite(boolean favorite) {
        isFavorite = favorite;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

}
```

> Adapter

```
public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private final Context context;
private final List<FavContact> contactList;
private final List<FavContact> filterList;
private final OnMyOwnClickListener onMyOwnClickListener;
private final FavContactRepo favContactRepo;

public ContactAdapter(Application application,Context context, List<FavContact> contactList, OnMyOwnClickListener onMyOwnClickListener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.contactList = contactList;
    this.onMyOwnClickListener = onMyOwnClickListener;
    filterList = new ArrayList<>(contactList);
    favContactRepo = new FavContactRepo(application);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.design_fav_contact, null, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view,onMyOwnClickListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final FavContact obj = contactList.get(position);
    holder.tv_contact_name.setText(obj.getName());

    holder.tv_contact_number.setText(obj.getNumber());

    if(obj.getImage()==null){
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_circle_fav_no_dp).fit().into(holder.img_contact);
    }
    else{
        Bitmap bp;
        try {
            bp = MediaStore.Images.Media
                    .getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(),
                            Uri.parse(obj.getImage()));
            Glide.with(context).load(bp).centerInside().into(holder.img_contact);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_circle_fav_no_dp).fit().into(holder.img_contact);
        }

    }
    obj.setFavorite(favContactRepo.checkIfFavourite(obj.getId()));

    if(obj.isFavorite()){
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_menu_favorite_true).into(holder.img_fav_true_or_not);
    }
    else{
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_menu_favorite_false).into(holder.img_fav_true_or_not);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    CircleImageView img_contact;
    TextView tv_contact_name,tv_contact_number;
    ImageView img_fav_true_or_not;
    ImageView img_call;
    RecyclerView fav_contact_rv;

    OnMyOwnClickListener onMyOwnClickListener;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnMyOwnClickListener onMyOwnClickListener) {
        super(itemView);
        img_contact = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_contact);
        tv_contact_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contact_name);
        img_fav_true_or_not = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_fav_true_or_not);
        tv_contact_number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contact_number);
        img_call = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_call);
        fav_contact_rv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fav_contact_rv);

        this.onMyOwnClickListener = onMyOwnClickListener;
        img_call.setOnClickListener(this);
        img_fav_true_or_not.setOnClickListener(this);
        img_contact.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onMyOwnClickListener.onMyOwnClick(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition(),view);
    }
}

public interface OnMyOwnClickListener{
    void onMyOwnClick(int position,View view);
}


@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return filteredList;
}

public Filter filteredList = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        List<FavContact> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            filteredList=filterList;
        } else {
            String filterText = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            for (FavContact item : filterList) {
                if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterText)
                        ||item.getNumber().toLowerCase().contains(filterText)) {
                    filteredList.add(item);
                }
            }

        }

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filteredList;

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        contactList.clear();
        contactList.addAll((ArrayList)results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
};
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: This is working.  There was a warning getColumnIndex can be -1