# Get all Contacts (Both from Phone and sim ) in a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contacts

I am a new developer . 
I am making app in which i want all Contacts in a listView . Contact name as main item and number as subitem .
I do some but i can't to get all contact ( both from phone and sim ) .

How to get all contacts ??
how to set the name as main item and the number as subitem ??

please help . thanks in advance .

Comment: are u asking about to fetch the native contact from device?

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the `ContactsContract` database using a `contentResolver`.
You can then use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to link this to your list view. There are quite a few examples of how to do this on the web if you search around, e.g.:

http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/how-to-access-contacts-in-android.html

Make sure you read up a bit on how the contacts are actually stored on Android as it is a slightly complicated 3-tier system:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/

I hope this will help.. 
and if you need to store contact to listview..
first you store all values in `arraylist`. 
and pass the `arraylist` to `adapter`. 
Then you display the contacts using `listview`

Answer (score 0):

Do query on `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` like you can see here : [get all contacts phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243278/android-get-all-contacts-telephone-number-in-arraylist). 
And do some research on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=get+contact+from+phone+android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&client=firefox-a#client=firefox-a&hs=2Rw&rls=org.mozilla:fr%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=get+all+contact+from+phone+android&oq=get+all+contact+from+phone+android&gs_l=serp.3...8105.8510.0.8637.4.4.0.0.0.1.359.359.3-1.1.0....0...1c.1.19.psy-ab.0lwmskVi28A&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.ZGU&fp=c3bb717ec45d5cfa&biw=1280&bih=863) from your own :).

For the ListView, search a tutorial to create a ListView.