# Obtain all contacts information including contact id, name, family, birhtday

Tags: android, arraylist, contacts

I know its a simple question, i searched a lot about it but i did not find a good solution.

I wanna obtain all contacts information including contact id, contact name, contact family, birthday ... and put them all in an ArrayList with objects,

Can any body help me or direct me to a good toturial ?

Thanks

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15243473/2553431)

Comment: no, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26820544/2252830)