# How to get phone number in oreo 8.1.0 of programmatically

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, telephonymanager

I used nokia 6 which is android 8.1.0 . i used this code for finding my phone number

```
TelephonyManager tel= (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String PhoneNumber =  tel.getLine1Number();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), PhoneNumber ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but it `return empty ("")`. on an other hand it's work fine my emulator. 
Please any one help me for this `oreo` solution.

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, give the following permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243278/android-get-all-contacts-telephone-number-in-arraylist and http://www.zeustechnocrats.com/android-read-contact-and-display-in-listview/  also https://www.concretepage.com/android/android-read-contact-name-and-phone-number-using-cursorloader-exampleAnd is there any contact available in your contact list?

Comment: actually i need my current use number from my phone not contact list