# How to get an URI array of all Android Contacts

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I am aware about the **Android Contact picker** which gives us the URI of any selected `Contact`.

The URI looks like this:
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r7-2C46324E483C324A3A484634/7

I need to get the URIs of all the contacts (something like a 'URI array') in the phone. Can someone help me out over doing this?

Comment: need to all contacts from device?

Comment: Can you describe more about your requirement ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all Contacts with the following query : `cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);`
Where `cr` is a `ContentResolver`.

Have a look here : [get all contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562151/android-get-all-contacts).

Comment: Thanks. I know that I can get Contact information (Name, phone number, mail ...) with this query. But I do not know how to get the URI of the contact.

Comment: To have the contact URI, you just need to append the contact id with the ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI like this : Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);

Comment: Tanks! Sorry for the question. But can you tell me how to get the ID of a User? I tried `c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.Contact_ID)` but it seems that this is wrong

Comment: String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
I took this line from the link in my answer, so I guess it works.