# Android Getting Contact list with phone numbers

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I'm creating an app which require Contacts with their phone numbers. I'm able to get the Contact name list using following code

```
private Contact[] contact_read;
private Cursor mCursor;

String[] projection = new String[] { Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
        Contacts._ID, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };

mCursor = managedQuery(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection,
        Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=?", new String[] { "1" },
        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

if (mCursor != null) {
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    contact_read = new Contact[mCursor.getCount()];

int j = 0;
    do {

        contact_read[j] = new Contact(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                .getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        j++;
    } while (mCursor.moveToNext());

} else {
    System.out.println("Cursor is NULL");
}
```

The Contact class is

```
private static class Contact {
    private String name = "";

    public Contact() {
    }

    public Contact(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

But when I add the following code to get phone number, the app crashes

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
String id = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID));
Cursor pCur = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
pCur.moveToFirst();

int j = 0;
do {
       contact_read[j] = new Contact(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER)));
        j++;
} while (pCur.moveToNext());
```

Any suggestions from your side what changes need to be done to get the phone numbers??

Comment: Here is the working code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562151/android-get-all-contacts

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for getting all the contacts from our phone

```
while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
          String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
          String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
           arraylist_connect.add(new Connect(name,phoneNumber,"Mobile"));

        }

        phones.close();
```