# No number assigned to contact

Tags: android, contacts

I've found this solution to loop contacts:

```
Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while(people.moveToNext()) {
                int nameFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
                String contact = people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
                int numberFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER);
                if (numberFieldColumnIndex >= 0) {
                    String number = people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);
                }
            }

    people.close();
```

`String contact = people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);` is working just fine, it stores all my contacts names, but `int numberFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER);` is always `-1`. Could you tell me where's the problem? Thank you :)

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562151/android-get-all-contacts

Answer (score 0):

Getting contact name correctly is just a co incidience.. as the value for **ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME** is "display_name" which is present in the result set.

And for **ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER** is "number" which is not present in the result set you get after quering using `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`

You can check which columns it will return by using following code first.

```
        if(people!=null){
        String[] colNames = people.getColumnNames();

        for(int i=0;i<colNames.length;i++)
            Log.i("",colNames[i]);
        }
```

Also do check the documentation for **PhoneLookup** by just moving your cursor on it (use intellij :) )

Here it is by the way:

*A table that represents the result of looking up a phone number, for example for caller ID. To 
 perform a lookup you must append the number you want to find to CONTENT_FILTER_URI. This query 
 is highly optimized. 
 Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
 resolver.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,...

**Columns**
PhoneLookup String NUMBER read-only Phone number. String TYPE read-only Phone number type. 
 See CommonDataKinds.Phone. String LABEL read-only Custom label for the phone number. See 
 CommonDataKinds.Phone. 
Columns from the Contacts table are also available through a join. Join with Contacts long _ID read-
 only Contact ID. String LOOKUP_KEY read-only See ContactsContract.Contacts String 
 DISPLAY_NAME read-only See ContactsContract.Contacts long PHOTO_ID read-only See 
 ContactsContract.Contacts. int IN_VISIBLE_GROUP read-only See ContactsContract.Contacts. int 
 HAS_PHONE_NUMBER read-only See ContactsContract.Contacts. int TIMES_CONTACTED read-only 
 See ContactsContract.Contacts. long LAST_TIME_CONTACTED read-only See 
 ContactsContract.Contacts. int STARRED read-only See ContactsContract.Contacts. String 
 CUSTOM_RINGTONE read-only See ContactsContract.Contacts. int SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL read-only 
 See ContactsContract.Contacts.*