# searching for contacts in content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am using this code to search for a contact

```
 String[] projection = new String[]
                {
                        Contacts.People.NAME,
                        Contacts.People.NUMBER
                };

        Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, Contacts.People.NAME + " ASC");
        c.moveToFirst();

        int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(Contacts.People.NAME);
        int numCol = c.getColumnIndex(Contacts.People.NUMBER);

        int nContacts = c.getCount();
        String result ="";

        do
        {
            String name = c.getString(nameCol);
            String number = c.getString(numCol);
            if (name.equals("XXXX")){
                result= number;
            }
        } while(c.moveToNext());
```

but I am getting  a nullPointerExeception on name.equals("XXXX") what would be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using deprecated `Contacts` class. It is better to use latest APIs. May be this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562151/android-get-all-contacts) can help you.