# Access phone book (contacts) using Kivy

Tags: android, kivy, contacts, android-contacts

I am developing a mobile app using Kivy. I would like to access the phone book (contact list). Is there an easy way like accessing the mobile sensors using plyer.

Note: I am not an android expert.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you'll need permission, add the **READ_CONTACTS** premission to your buildozer spec.

Now, you should use **pyjnius** to use the Java SDK like this:

-*this is not tested*-

```
  PythonActivity=autoclass("org.renpy.android.PythonActivity")
  ContactsContract=autoclass("android.provider.ContactsContract")

  cr = PythonActivity.mActivity.getContentResolver()
  null = None # this will help to convert java examples into python ones :)
  cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                 null, null, null, null)
  if (cur.getCount() > 0):
      while (cur.moveToNext()):
          id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
          name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)) #I think this is not DISPLAY_NAME in all versions ...
          print("->", id, name)

        #you can further query contact by its id
```

the logic is taken from this answer: [android get all contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562151/android-get-all-contacts)

There is also this pull request for **plyer** that you might want to test: https://github.com/kivy/plyer/pull/125/

Answer (score 0):

I needed this and searched a lot but couldn't find solution which is full code and understandable. I hope these explanations will be enough to figure out.

Accessing correctly `PythonActivity`:

```
PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity")
```

Accessing `Contacts` Java Class:

```
Contacts = autoclass("android.provider.ContactsContract$Contacts")
```

Accessing `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` Java Class (same):

```
Kinds = autoclass("android.provider.ContactsContract$CommonDataKinds$Phone")
```

Creating `getContentResolver()`:

```
cr = PythonActivity.mActivity.getContentResolver()
```

Now we need to create 2 query. In first, we are going to find **`ID`** and need to use it in second query to find equal **`NUMBER`**. Also need to check ***is contact has phone number?*** too. After that we can loop second query to find number:

```
name_number_dict= {}   # Name:Number  # Change as you wish..
    while (que1.moveToNext()):  #Query 1 Loop
        if que1.getString(que1.getColumnIndex(Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)):  #If has number
            que2 = cr.query(Kinds.CONTENT_URI, None, Kinds.CONTACT_ID + " = " + que1.getString(que1.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_ID)), None, None)  #Query 2 Loop
            while (que2.moveToNext()):
                name_number_dict[que1.getString(que1.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))] = que2.getString(que2.getColumnIndex(Kinds.NUMBER)  # Get datas and put in dic.
```

- If you need to check all ColumnNames of query, use `query1.getColumnNames()`  >> [Referance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor?authuser=2#getColumnNames())
- If you need to find count : `query1.getCount()` will be useful.