# Android: How import contacts from device address book to my android app?

Tags: android

Android 4.3. 
I write android application that show/edit/add/remove conacts that user input.

But I has many contacts in my adress book on device. So I want to imprort all this conacts from device adress book to my android application. How I can do this?

Comment: have you tried using search? Your problem has been solved for over 100 times already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android get all contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562151/android-get-all-contacts)

Answer (score 2):

Use **ContentProvider** components in your application.
ContentProvider definition according to Android documentation:

> Content providers can help an application manage access to data stored
>   by itself, stored by other apps, and provide a way to share data with
>   other apps. They encapsulate the data, and provide mechanisms for
>   defining data security.
>   Follow the link to learn about content provider
>   [codetutor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4GgzqMVrYc/%22codetutor%22)

else follow the [vogella tutorial about contacts](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#tutorial-using-contentprovider)

Answer (score 0):

you will use content resolver api to query your phone book and retrieve contacts list .this is useful
[tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/provider/android-contacts-example/)