# How to sort retrieved contacts by type?

Tags: java, android

I figured out how to retrieve all the contacts in my phone using the 4th answear in this question. [android get all contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562151/android-get-all-contacts)

Now I want to sort them by type
Ex:
Google contacts;
Sim contacts
etc.
All of them in seperate lists.

What property from the cursor will give me the type of the contact so I could be able to put it in the respective list?

It must be something like "contactType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract. Contacts.GET_TYPE));"

Comment: Provide us with what you have tried and we can better assist you.

Comment: Well... I don;t think it's something that I should try. I know the mechanism. It must be something like "contactType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.
                            Contacts.GET_TYPE));". I can't find something concludent. A link or a possible dublicate that I missed would be very helpful

Comment: print logs for all relevant columns and you will have your answer