# How Can I list all mobile contacts on an App Android

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I started to learn Mobile App Development with Android Studios. I want to create a simple app(for testing) where I display all cellphone contacts in a ListView.

I have the main activity and its xml file where I have added a ListView element, I want to display all contacts there.

This is the code of the main activity class:

```
package com.example.contactlist;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
}
```

this is the code of the main activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:title="Contact Lists" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtitulo_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact Lists"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.087"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.119" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listado_contactos"
    android:layout_width="346dp"
    android:layout_height="644dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subtitulo_container"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_multiple_choice" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is the code of the AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.contactlist">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

What I want to know is how can I get all contacts data from the cellphone and display them in my ListView?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've developed a utility class to retrieve device contacts. It's available on GitHub:

#### [ContactUtils.kt](https://github.com/aminography/CommonUtils/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/aminography/commonutils/ContactUtils.kt)

Since handling all situations that might happen in retrieving contacts is a bit time consuming, I suggest you get this file and add it to your project. It's written in `kotlin`, but if you are using `java`, also it's possible to get the list of contacts like the following:

```
List<ContactData> contacts = ContactUtilsKt.retrieveAllContacts(context);

// or to retrieve all contacts matching specific search pattern:
List<ContactData> contacts = ContactUtilsKt.retrieveAllContacts(context, "John");
```

Comment: Cool, Thanks, I'll test this function. So, I'm using Java for create the app, Can I create a kotlin file with your class and call it in Main Activity with the code you post above in this answer?

Comment: You're welcome :) Sure, Java and kotlin are fully interoperable, so if you are writing in Java, no problem, it's just needed to add the kotlin dependency in `build.gradle` then use the kotlin class in the Java code.

Comment: @RolandF: Would it be successful?

Comment: It doesn't work, the app never open if use the kotlin class

Comment: Too weird problem! Do you mean that it crashes?

Comment: yes, it crashes. It's something weird. I haven't found a way to make it works

Comment: It'd be great if you share with me the logcat content about the crash. However, I've written a test activity class that shows the contacts list. It works fine. Please compare your code with it: https://github.com/aminography/CommonUtils/blob/master/java-sample-app/src/main/java/com/aminography/commonutils/sample/ContactUtilsTestActivity.java

Comment: This finally work! Thank you. I did check the main code once and once again and I did realize that I had an error in two variables.

Comment: If I want, for example, update the phone number from a contact, I can do it only with the ID of the Contact?

Comment: You're welcome :) I'm grateful to see the issue has been solved. Yes, by having contact Id, it's possible to update contact details easily.

Comment: cool, Thanks to you. Is there a way to convert the List<ContactData> in Array of data. ?

Comment: Yes, here is the solution to convert a list to an array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9572820/1631967

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function from which you can get contacts

```
private void getContactList() {
  ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
  Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
          null, null, null, null);

  if ((cur != null ? cur.getCount() : 0) > 0) {
      while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
          String id = cur.getString(
                  cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
          String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                  ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

          if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(
                  ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
              Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                      null,
                      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                      new String[]{id}, null);
              while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                  String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                          ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                  Log.i(TAG, "Name: " + name);
                  Log.i(TAG, "Phone Number: " + phoneNo);
              }
              pCur.close();
          }
      }
  }
  if(cur!=null){
    cur.close();
  }
}
```

Reference [android-get-all-contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562151/android-get-all-contacts)

Comment: Thanks, I'll be testing this code. Can I add this function in the Main Activity Class, right?

Comment: When I use this code, the app doesn't open. It closes before it starts.

Comment: check where it crushes you can find it in logcat

Comment: if this code is crashing then you need to add permission for reading contact in manifest

Answer (score 1):

you must push or set list to your adapter

```
public List<String> getNumber(ContentResolver cr)
{
    List<String> phonebook = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
    // use the cursor to access the contacts
    while (phones.moveToNext())
    {
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        phonebook.add(phoneNumber);
    }
    return phonebook;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the aceepted answer, but everytime i used to get my list of particluar contactId as 0

```
val result: MutableList<ContactData> = mutableListOf()
contentResolver.query(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
    CONTACT_PROJECTION,
    if (searchPattern.isNotBlank()) "${ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY} LIKE '%?%'" else null,
    if (searchPattern.isNotBlank()) arrayOf(searchPattern) else null,
    if (limit > 0 && offset > -1) "${ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY} ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset"
    else ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " ASC"
)?.use {
    if (it.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            val contactId = it.getLong(it.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_PROJECTION[0]))
            val name = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_PROJECTION[2])) ?: ""
            val hasPhoneNumber = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_PROJECTION[3])).toInt()
            val phoneNumber: List<String> = if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                retrievePhoneNumber(contactId)
            } else mutableListOf()

            val avatar = if (retrieveAvatar) retrieveAvatar(contactId) else null
            result.add(ContactData(contactId, name, phoneNumber, avatar))
        } while (it.moveToNext())
    }
}
return result
```

for this first part of code as it internally calls **retrivePhoneNumber(contactId)**

```
val result: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
contentResolver.query(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
    null,
    "${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID} =?",
    arrayOf(contactId.toString()),
    null
)?.use {
    if (it.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            result.add(it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)))
        } while (it.moveToNext())
    }
}
return result
```

here in this block of code **it.moveToFirst()** always false, so returned list is always zero

Here is the working code which will return all list number as list excluding those number who is the same number but space in it like **+91123 344 55**

```
val contactsNumberMap = HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>()
val result: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        context.contentResolver.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        )?.use { c ->
            val contactIdIndex =
                c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID)
            val numberIndex = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                val contactId = c.getString(contactIdIndex)
                val number: String = c.getString(numberIndex)
                if (number.contains(' ').not()) {
                    if (contactsNumberMap.containsKey(contactId)) {
                        contactsNumberMap[contactId]?.add(number)
                    } else {
                        contactsNumberMap[contactId] = hashSetOf(number)
                    }
                }
            }
            contactsNumberMap.map { m ->
                m.apply {
                    value.forEach {
                        result.add(it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return@withContext result
    }
    return result
```